# How to Create HDFS file

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, snakebite

I know it is possible to create directory HDFS with python using snakebite

But I am looking to create a file on HDFS directory

Comment: Please share code you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using subprocess

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE 

(ret, out, err)= run_cmd(['hdfs', 'dfs', '-touchz', '/directory/filename'])
```

Comment: You said you didn't want to use native cmd commands. You may as well use a bash script instead of Python, then

Comment: I used native hadoop cmd but with python

Answer (score 0):

You can use `touchz` to create an empty file on HDFS...

I see `rename` command in the docs, which might accept local source with a remote HDFS path for uploading files, but [there is no `put` or `copyFromLocal` CLI command](https://snakebite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html), so I don't think Snakebite can do what you want.

I do see  [`put`](https://snakebite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minicluster.html#snakebite.minicluster.MiniCluster.put) for the minicluster.

---

Overall, you may have better luck with `pyspark` or [`hdfs`](https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#reading-and-writing-files) depending on your needs.

Comment: I don't want to use hadoop native cmd like put, touch .....

Comment: want I want is python script to create new hdfs file on a hadoop directory

Comment: 1) snakebite touchz does create a file 2) None of those links are to native cmd. Look at the linked hdfs library, then., if you don't want to create an empty file, and would rather upload existing local data to hdfs